# Problems to get the child data from entity class (via SESSION)

Tags: symfony, session, doctrine, entity, lazy-loading

I just starting with doctrine / symfony and I am facing the following issue:

#### Background

I have 3 Entities:

1. Course
2. Pricing
3. Discounts

Each Course is connectect to a pricing. A pricing can be used for multiple courses.
Each pricing has different discounts (pending on the date of booking).

#### What I did:

I added a function into the Course-Entity to get the current price

```
class Course {
   // Remark: I will skip the doctine annontation in this example
   
   // properties corresponding to database
   private $name
   private $basicprice
   [...]

   // getters and setters for the properties
   [...]

   // getter to related entities
   public function getPricing() {...}

   // additional functions
   public function getCurrentPrice() {
      dump($this->getPricing());
      dump($this->getPricing()->getName());
      dump($this->getPricing());

      $discounts = $this->getPricing()->getDiscounts(); // <-- BIG ERROR

      // +++ do some magic logic +++
      $currentDiscount = magic();
      $currentPrice    = $this->getBasicPrice() - $currentDiscount; 
     
      return $currentPrice;
   }
}
```

#### What I want:

The Course-Object is stored in SESSION and shall now be treated

```
class BookingController extends AbstractController {
   [...]
   
   public function index() {
      $session = new Session();
      $course  = $session->get('course')
      $price   = $course->getCurrentPrice();
      [...]
   }
}
```

#### Issue

While I can get the PRICING and the DISCOUNTS with other controllers, I assume that the problem is in the usage of SESSION.

I don't get the DISCOUNTS (error), but the problem is I guess already on PRICING-Level. See the DUMPs:

```
Course.php on line 68:
Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Pricing {#948 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 456
  -name: null
  -createdAt: null
  -updatedAt: null
  -courses: null
  -discounts: null
   …2
}

Course.php on line 69:
null

Course.php on line 70:
Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Pricing {#948 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 456
  -name: null
  -createdAt: null
  -updatedAt: null
  -courses: null
  -discounts: null
   …2
}
```

#### Questions

1. Is that additional function in the Course-Class correctly placed? Or does it need to go into a subclass of Course-Class?
2. Why do I not get the wanted data already on PRICING-Level?

Many thanks for your ideas!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that an Object passed via SESSION is 'dead', so that Lazy-Loading is not working anymore.

The Object needs first to be 're-animated'. After this Lazy-Loading is working again:

```
class BookingController extends AbstractController {
   [...]
   
   public function index() {
      $session   = new Session();
      $course    = $session->get('course')
      $course_id = $course->getId();
      $course    = $this->courseReository->find($course_id);
      $price     = $course->getCurrentPrice();
      [...]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's ok, that entity Pricing dumped as not initialized. It works on lazy-load, so when you'll call any methods of Pricing it would work properly.

About your questions:

1. I think it's better to place the method for calculating price with discounts right into the Pricing entity. Just because discounts are still about pricing, not about courses;
2. As I said, try to dump any get method of Pricing entity or even Discount get-method. It'll work.

Comment: Many thanks for taking your time to support me. I was already searching in the direction of Lazy-Loading. Unfortunatelly calling a method on PRICING-Level does not help. See my updated question, where I added the additional dumps. Anything I can check?

Comment: I checked in parallel other things and saw, that the problem is only happening, when I pass the object via SESSION.

Comment: When I rechecked your issue I used just CourseRepo with `find(id)` method and it worked. So, not sure that problem at the session as at ID storage. But yeah, I see your example... So, I'll try to reproduce